# Call function from Scala in Java

Tags: java, scala

I have the following function in Scala:

```
object Path {

  def process: String => String =
    ???
}
```

and then trying to call in Java as:

```
KStream<String, String> source = builder
    .stream("PATHS-UPSERT-PRODUCER", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
    .mapValues(value -> Path.process(value));
```

The compiler complains:

```
[error]   required: no arguments
[error]   found: java.lang.String
[error]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[error]         .mapValues(value -> Path.process(value));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks more like a Apache Kafka problem than like a Scala problem - you might want to add the appropriate Kafka tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `process` in your example is a function of type `String => String`, **To invoke a function, you need to call `apply()` on it.**

Scala by default invokes `apply` when client code uses parenthsis `()`, but java won't recognise that.

```
object Path {
    def process: String => String = (input: String) => "processed"
}

scala> process("some value")
res88: String = processed

scala> process.apply("some value")
res89: String = processed
```

NOTE: The expanded version of scala function is,

```
  def process = new Function[String, String] {
    override def apply(input: String) = "processed"
  }
```

**invoking from java,**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path f = new Path();
        System.out.println(f.process().apply("som input")); //prints processed
    }
}
```

Comment: I've forgot to mention process is a composed function: `def process: String => String = decode compose verify compose encode`.

Comment: You should be able to invoke a function by explicitly calling `.apply` on a function which is because scala by default calls apply function when you call `functionName(value)` but java can not do that, so `functionName().apply(value)` is what you need.

Comment: One more Problem left. I have `final case class Path(os: Os, data: List[String], error: String)` and  `object Path {}`, the compiler is confuse, which definition, it should take. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: It should be fine though as long as you invoke as `Path.process().apply("some-data")` What is the error you get?

Comment: I was trying to `Path f = new Path();` then I've got that companion object are static in java. `cannot find symbol [error]   symbol:   constructor Path() [error]  location: class io.khinkali.Path [error]           Path f = new Path();`

Comment: Ughh, sorry for that in my answer. Since you have a data class with the same name `Path`, you need to pass in all the values for os, data and error in a constructor. instead of newing it up, you can static call `Path.process()`.